# How can you set a variable in Linux that is almost impossible to reset

Tags: android, linux, variables

The title says it all.

It is known that Android has an Internal variable that is set to 1 when you unlock the bootloader, or disable SELinux or something.

Is it possible to set such a variable so that no one can reset it afterwards.

This is like breaking a fuse, but only using software.

Comment: The [`initramfs`](https://wiki.debian.org/initramfs) is generally R/O (despite being loaded into RAM).

Comment: Yes I get that it is RO but I don't get how that relate to the problem

Comment: The problem is an absurd concept, while this 0/1 switch is on the `localhost`... even when restoring it with every reboot, one can always overwrite variables in shell script.

Comment: What do you mean, `localhost`? And I don't think it absurd because why is Android using it then?

Comment: Why can I enable / disable SE Linux? This argument is no argument ... and Android basically is being loaded from `initramfs`, too. The whole system partition is read-only.

Comment: It is used in Android because if you don't disable SELinux, you can't install a custom ROM or unlock the bootloader or even root your device.

Comment: This is non-sense. Maybe unlock and root a few phones and build AOSP a few times?

Comment: That is the whole problem, unless the SELinux mode set to permissive, you can't install your custom ROM (OS), because there is some security mechanism that check the validity of OS components at boot time. If you install a custom ROM without the SELinux switch, your device will be bricked, Trust me, I have a bricked J6 rn.

Comment: That you have bricked something is probably proof how much you understand of what you're talking about and your logic makes no sense at all, because you need root to disable it, while you claim you need to disable it to gain root (there's actually not even any need to disable it). And I honestly fail to see the relation to programming with this question ...

Comment: I flashed a custom OS using Odin to my Android, while forgetting SELinux is still on. At boot time, SELinux checks the OS and find that it has changed. et voila: brick.

Comment: The relation in programming is that once the SELinux fuse is killed, it can never be unkilled, and I believe they do this with software, so why not do it ourselves? Maybe modify the kernel or something